# select option react with react-router BUG

Tags: reactjs

I have a select option and I want to link the user to another comp when clicked
everything going well,the user is redirected and see the comp. But, the option doesn't change in the select label, and still shows the first option all the time.
 see code below:

```
`

    <Select portfolio dir="rtl" 
            onChange={(e)=>{
              history.push(`${e.target.value}`); 
              }}>
     <Option value='/account/details'>details</Option>
      <Option value='/account/projects' >projects</Option>
      <Option value='/account/changepassword'>pass</Option>
      {user&& (
      <Option value='/account/requests'>messages</Option>
      )}
      </Select>
      );
    };

`
```

*edit*
i use the regular select input .
and still dont understand the problem.
in other component i have this select option (without link) and its work and change the "title text" op the option when i change.

its looking the same and its work:

```
    <Select small dir="rtl" 
        onChange={(e)=>{
          return catFilter(e.target.value)
          }}>

  <Option key='' value=''>all</Option>;
{categories&&categories.map((opt, key) => {
        return <Option key={key} value={opt.id}>{opt.fullName}</Option>;

      })}

      </Select>
```

i dont see the difference...

Comment: you need to pass the current value to the Select component. depending on the components props expectations it will probably be the "value" prop

Comment: :/.. still dont  understand.
note that i have another select option exactly the same but without the link o react-router and its work perfectly.
so i think its some issue with the react-router

Comment: The select component is the one "knowing" which of the options is selected. however at the moment it doesn't. you need to provide the `value` prop to Select. which component library do you use?

Comment: i still dont understand why change the state, i have same select option in another comp (without Link) and its worked perfectly.
 (i edited the post so see code there..)

Comment: i think that the problem is that i have <form> inside the options and its render all or somehing, anyway problem solved thank u